# How to avoid writing jQuery repetitive code

Tags: jquery

I have searched and the questions tab, I found the jQuery repetitive code question has been asked before, but I still can't understand how to apply it to my specific issue.

Below is a simple code that changes the text in a box to red, blue and black, there are 3 of this boxes. how do I minimise this code to avoid repetition, thanks.

```
 $("div.box1").click(function () {
    colour=$(this).css("background-color");
    $("div.first").css("color", colour);
});

 $("div.box2").click(function () {
    colour=$(this).css("background-color");
    $("div.second").css("color", colour);
});

 $("div.box3").click(function () {
    colour=$(this).css("background-color");
    $("div.last").css("color", colour);
});
```

Comment: post your question in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you need three colors for each box? Why not to do that in CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your HTML its hard to understand how these different elements relate.

However one thing you could do is store the class name of the element having its color updated as a HTML5 attribute. For example:

```
<div class="box box1" data-otherdiv="first"></div>
<div class="box box2" data-otherdiv="second"></div>
<div class="box box3" data-otherdiv="third"></div>
```

Then you can simply use the one function:

```
$("div.box").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this); //creating a local "$this" object prevents multiple $(this) calls
    $("div." + $this.data("otherdiv")).css("color", $this.css("background-color"));
});
```

Comment: if the html5 then this is the best way and if you want to use data then you can make the selector same. Means : make the class name same "box" and put the only ".box" selector in selector.

Comment: @PathikGandhi I don't agree with replacing `box1` with `box` (as `box1` could potentially have a CSS rule specifically). However I do agree that a shared class should be added. I've therefore amended my code to include `box` and only reference this in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Start out with defining a function that has a more generic version of the functionality. The only difference is the selctor for the div to be coloured so take that out as a parameter and you get

```
function setColor (divSelector) {
    var colour=$(this).css("background-color");
    $(divSelector).css("color", colour);
});
```

you'd then use it like this

```
$("div.box1").click(function () {
    setColor("div.first");
});
//...and so on for the following boxes
```

you could be even smarter than this and have the divSelector selected based on `this` E.g. You could use jQuery `.data()` to connect the divs. In contrast to using `data-*` jQuerys data works in older browsers as well

That would allow you to change the code to

```
function setColor () {
    var self = $(this);
    var colour=self.css("background-color");
    $("div." + self.data('toBeColoured')).css("color", colour);
});
```

or use `data-*` if you only need to support HTML5 browsers

and then just use it as below

```
$("div.box1").data('toBeColoured','first').click(setColor);
$("div.box2").data('toBeColoured','second').click(setColor);
$("div.box3").data('toBeColoured','last').click(setColor);
```

as an aside first,second and last can be selected using pseudo selectors so often there should be no need for ordering based classes

Comment: Here below is the html, I have found your comments very useful, but I haven't been able to uniquely change each of the boxes(first, second and third) yet.<div class="first content_bg">
   <p id="text1">
    Ut aliquam lobortis tincidunt. Sed egestas nunc id tellus egestass.
   </p>
   <div class="colours">
    <div class="box1 blue"></div>
    <div class="box1 red"></div>
    <div class="box1 black"></div>
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: @user1478720 can you show the html for the div's going to be changed? are they all changed at the same time or are none changed?

Answer (score -2):

At least two ways:

**1)** Use selector engine to select multiple elements and apply a function to them:

```
 $("div.box1, div.box2, div.box").click(function () {
    colour=$(this).css("background-color");
    $("div.first").css("color", colour);
});
```

**2)** Have a function which does the thing and Dont Repeat Yourself(**DRY**)

```
 function applyColor() {
   colour=$(this).css("background-color");
   $("div.second").css("color", colour);
 }
 $("div.box1").click(function () {
   applyColor();
 });

 $("div.box2").click(function () {
   applyColor();
 });

 $("div.box3").click(function () {
   applyColor();
 });
```

Comment: I don't see a reason to use the colour variable. You can just use a one-line statement.

Comment: Note that `$("div.box3").click(applyColor)` etc. would be the same here. The OP should also realise he's declaring an implicit global (`colour`) by not prefixing it with `var`.

Comment: You missed the fact that a different `div` is recolored each time.

Comment: @JanDvorak, missed that. Thanks for the insight.